# Counting number of rows a value occurs in across a range of columns

Tags: excel, counting

This is my first question so hopefully I'll manage to make sense.

I have the following spreadsheet.  In the Column A is the Point code, Column B is Record A and Column C is Record B.  The point code is just free text and then Record A and B have one of the following values, Absent, R, O, F, A or D.  I want to find all the points (i.e. rows) that have D in either column B or C.  Some rows may have no D, some may have D in one column and some may have it in both columns.

How do I do this?  I need to do it without making any extra columns, i.e converting all the D to 1's and then summing the two columns and counting anything >0.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you posted a table-like sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT`, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B1000="D")+(C2:C1000="D")>0)+0)`

That will count any row that has 1 or 2 "D"s, adjust ranges as required